# What's the difference between keyup, keydown, keypress and input events?

Tags: javascript, input

I have been trying to understand JavaScript `keypress`, `keydown`, `keyup` and **input** events. But I found them quite confusing. Could someone please point out the exact differences? Also I would like to know do all of them get triggered when the user paste a piece of text.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

According to [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/):

> The **keypress** event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. This is similar to the **keydown** event, except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events. Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.
>
> The **keyup** event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.
>
> The **oninput** event it's an event that triggers whenever the input changes.

However the input event is not supported in IE version below 9. In that case, you could use proprietary event onpropertychange, it does the same as oninput.

But in your case, you could use the **paste** and **change** event together. You should use **change** too because **paste** only happens on browsers that support it on an explicit paste.

Comment: At leat on chrome (63) where I am testing, keypress and keydown are triggered **before** the event is processed, so the key event hasn't changed the input's value, yet.
Input, on the other hand, is processed after.
That means if you access the inputs value, you will get the _previous_ value on the keypress and keydown event listeners.

Comment: @RSinohara - thats funny - I'm on Chromium on Linux - "68.0.3440.106" (64 bit).  The behavior I see is the **EXACT** opposite.  Go figure.

Comment: If you're trying to listen to user hitting enter key to trigger some action, you need to use keypress or keyup, because enter doesn't change the field value (so input won't fire).

Comment: Alternatively, inside keydown you can use setTimeout(()=>e.target.value, 0), to get the value after the key is added (if you're using vanilla js)

Comment: @RSinohara Use the `keyup` event for the updated input value

Answer (score 2):

Since [this is being treated as the definitive JS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718122/javascript-addeventlistener-input-versus-keyup) (rather than just a jQuery answer) here's a  **current standard JavaScript answer with MDN references**:

- [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) - fired when the content changes. This includes mouse pastes and non-keyboard input.
- [`keyup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) - fired when a key is released. This includes shift key, control key, and other keys that don't change the value of input elements.

[Docs for all events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)