# JavaScript addEventListener : 'input' versus 'keyup'

Tags: javascript

I use the 'keyup' event when I want to get the value of a text-input immediately after insertion.

Now I've seen in a CodeReview question the usage of an event 'input' for to accomplish the same.

*The CodeReview question (5th line):* https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141937/registration-form-validation-in-jquery

I've tinkered a bit. Made this demo:

```js
var box = document.querySelector('input');

box.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  console.log('keyup: %s', this.value);
});

box.addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log('input: %s', this.value);
});

/* RESULT
  input: a
  keyup: a
  input: ab
  keyup: ab
  input: abc
  keyup: abc
*/
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

As one can see: No difference!

Therefore my question:

**Is there a difference between the usage of the keyup-event and the input-event (for reading the value of a text-input)?**

And:

**Are there cases in which one should prefer the one over the other?**

Comment: Yes! If you paste the value using `right-click`, `keyup-handler` will not invoke but `input-handler` will... Few other differences are there as well...

Comment: I am amazed I could not find exact _dupe_..

Comment: May be [__http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502560/diffrence-between-keyup-keydown-keypress-and-input-events__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502560/diffrence-between-keyup-keydown-keypress-and-input-events)

Comment: mouse up is when you mouse up your keyboard within that element while input is when you put something on an input element

Comment: Okay. I know the difference now. If you type: "a", "b", "c" then you both events are triggered. But if you then do mouse right-click and choose "Paste" from the context menu. So that the current content of your clipboard it copied into the textbox then you see that ONLY the input event is triggered. Conclusion: The input-event is triggered whenever the value of the text-input changes. The keyup-event is only triggered when the keyboard is involved.

Answer (score 13):

Key up event also detects the control keys like enter,Ctrl,backspace,delete etc 
on the  other hand input event in initiated only for characters numbers and  symbols. This is the one difference i found,

Key-up listens all keys

input listens only the characters ,numbers and special characters keys

Comment: Are you sure ? I do not think this is correct! Check this out – `<input type="text">
    $('input').on('keyup', function () {
        console.log(this.value);
    });`

Comment: @Rayon Please point out the mistake

Comment: Do run code I have shared, Hit `ctrl` key..

Comment: Yes it listens to the ctrl button

Comment: Now hit `a-z` keys...

Comment: it listens to those too

Comment: You said — "Key up event detects the control keys like enter,Ctrl,backspace,delete etc"

Comment: Please check the answer now ,i repeat  Keyup listens to all keys , 
Input event listens to the alphanumeric, special characters keys .
input also detects the paste event

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124266/discussion-between-mukul-jayaprakash-and-rayon).

Comment: `KeyUp` does not work properly on android devices