# Does 'keypress' jQuery event fire before an inputs value is updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a keypress event listener on an input field to confirm a password. I want the `button` on the page to be disabled until the `password` and `confirm-password` fields have matching values. I am using the `.keypress()` jQuery function, but it seems to always be one character behind what I expect it to be?

Here is the code

```
$('#confirm').keypress(function() {
    console.log('#confirm').val();
    if($('#password').val() == $('#confirm').val()) {
        $('button').removeProp('disabled');
        console.log("yes");                
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

But when I inspect element and look at the console window on my page, the first time the event is fired it prints the form value as blank. Then when I enter a second character, it prints only the first, and when I type a third character it prints the first two, etc.

For example, if I put `asd` into the `password` field and begin typing the same into the `confirm` field the output will look like this:

`<blank>
no
a
no
as
no`

So at this point both `password` and `confirm` fields have "asd", but I need to enter an extra character before that is recognized and the "disabled" property is removed from the button.

I have tried using `.change()` instead of `.keypress()` but that doesn't fire until the `input` field loses focus, which is not what I want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502560/diffrence-between-keyup-keydown-keypress-and-input-events

Comment: You can try using the `keyup` event instead, it should trigger after the user releases the key - https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: Make sure you include some other indication that they don't match, other than a disabled button - that would _really_ frustrate me as a user

Comment: use the `input` event; that's what it's for, and it works with mouse pasting, IME, etc

Comment: @JamesThorpe There are other visual cues, I agree with the frustration haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the button on the page to be disabled until the password and confirm-password fields have matching values

If this is your goal, you can add event listeners to both inputs that call a validation function:

```
$('#password').on("input", function() { validatePassword(); });

$('#confirm').on("input", function() { validatePassword(); });

function validatePassword() {
    if($('#password').val() && $('#confirm').val() && $('#password').val() == $('#confirm').val()) {
        $('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

It also may be worthwhile adding an ID to the button. Using 'button' would enable/disable all  elements on the page.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/doL4t9vv/1/

Comment: There is only one button on the page, so disabling all buttons is not a concern.

Comment: Gotchya. Then what I have answered should work fine then. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: first 2 lines could easily be combined to `$('#confirm, #password').on('input', validatePassword)`

Comment: I agree that they could be combined like this. However, what if you'd like to add additional logic to one input specifically, or call more than one function? For example, if you are validating a username, you can call one function to check availability (asynchronous) and another function to check for valid characters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem few months ago.
**Try to use the `keyup` function from Jquery.**

Keypress event is fired when you press the key, so the input is not fill yet.
Keyup event is fired when you release the key.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `input` event and simplify this down to

```
var $passwords =$('#confirm, #password').on('input', function() {
    var thisValue = this.value.trim();
    // does this input have value and does it match other
    var isValid = thisValue  && thisValue  === $passwords.not(this).val().trim();
    // boolean used for disabled property    
    $('button').prop('disabled', !isValid);      
});
```

Comment: I think I prefer the extra lines of code for the added legibility ;) haha

Comment: Why trim the value? What if someone has a space in the first field but not in the second? E.g. password="test123" and confirm="test123 ". They are not equal and should not be treated that way. :)

Comment: fixed...trimmed them both

Comment: I was saying that you should not trim at all.

Comment: "password123" and "password123 " would enable the button, when it shouldn't. Especially if they want the password to have a space at the end.

Comment: @John-PaulEnsign why not? If user has equal number empty spaces and no other characters in both would pass

Comment: Test it out. https://jsfiddle.net/0khvo210/ I left it as 'text' instead of 'password' for visibility. Try the password '<space>test123<space><space>' and for confirm simply put 'test123'. The button will be enabled. Spaces are allowed in passwords and shouldn't be trimmed.

Comment: have never seen any password that is viable with space on either end...that would be horrible to maintain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134628/discussion-between-john-paul-ensign-and-charlietfl).