# catch .on('change) of textbox within modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that contains a text box. I would like to allow the user to simply type in the box and, when their input meets the requirement (length 4), call a function. The issue is the .on('change') function only seems to be processed when you click somewhere in the modal, or close the modal.

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and jquery 3.1.1

```js
$('#signInModal').modal('show');

$('#signInModal-passwordText').on('change', function() {
  //some diagnostic stuff
  $('#signInModal-failedSpan').show();
  $('#signInModal-failedSpan').html($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val().length == 4) {
    //alert('4');
    signIn($(this).val());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="signInModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="signInModal-passwordText" type="password" class="form-control" />
        <span class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;" role="alert" id="signInModal-failedSpan">Failed!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: did you tried `on('input',`

Comment: on("keyup" is another one to try

Comment: I made you a snippet - next time do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use onkeyup since change needs a blur in many browsers to trigger:

[Diffrence between keyup keydown keypress and input events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38502560/diffrence-between-keyup-keydown-keypress-and-input-events)

```js
function signIn(val) { alert(val)}
$('#signInModal').modal('show');

$('#signInModal-passwordText').on('keyup', function() {
  //some diagnostic stuff
  $('#signInModal-failedSpan').show();
  $('#signInModal-failedSpan').html($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val().length == 4) {
    signIn($(this).val());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="signInModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="signInModal-passwordText" type="password" class="form-control" />
        <span class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;" role="alert" id="signInModal-failedSpan">Failed!</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but this might help someone else.

You could have changed this line:

```
$('#signInModal-passwordText').on('change', function() {
```

to:

```
$('.modal').on('change', '#signInModal-passwordText', function() {
```